# How to access mapped type by index

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to wrap my head around the following behavior, say I have the following type definitions

```js
type RMap = {
    a: { foo: string }
    b: { foo: unknown }
}

type RType = keyof RMap

type RState = {
    [k: string]: {
        s: RMap[RType]
    }
}
```

Given these, what's the difference between `f1` and `f2` below? Why does the first one not compile?

```js
declare const map: RState

function f1<R extends RType>(k: string, f: (r: RMap[R]) => void): void {
    f(map[k].s)
}

function f2(k: string, f: (r: RMap[RType]) => void): void {
    f(map[k].s)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work becasue `R extends RType` is wider than `RType`.

`RType` is `'a' | 'b'`, no other options.

`R extends RType` fits `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`, that breaks `r: RMap[UNEXPECTED_KEYS]`.